# Placing recent commits in a separate (named) branch in Mercurial (Hg)

Tags: mercurial, branch, tortoisehg

If I have several commits made to the default branch since the last push, is it possible to go back, and move those commits into a separate named branch?

That is, I have:

```
A--B--C--D
```

and I want:

```
A
 \
  B--C--D
```

I hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [Transplant](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension) extension.

But personally, I'd do it using MQ, like so:

```
# assuming revs 1 and 2 are the ones we want to move
hg qimport -r1:2

# qimport creates a patch for each changeset
>hg qapplied
1.diff
2.diff

# pop the patches, to save for later
>hg qpop -a
popping 2.diff
popping 1.diff
patch queue now empty

# switch branches
>hg branch my-branch
marked working directory as branch my-branch

# push our saved changesets, essentially rebasing on the new branch
>hg qpush -a
applying 1.diff
applying 2.diff
now at: 2.diff

# make the patches part of permanent history
>hg qfin -a
```

You could probably also bend the [Rebase](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) extension to suit this purpose, if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

If the commits are still in only your local repository and have not been pushed to any other one, then yes, you can re-arrange them with fairly minimal trouble. If they have moved beyond just your local repo, however, you will run into a lot of trouble.

To re-arrange commits, you want to use the [MQ](https://wiki.mercurial-scm.org/MqExtension) extension. [Here's a tutorial](https://wiki.mercurial-scm.org/MqTutorial), since it explains things better than I could here.